# Error 53 when updating Active Directory password with Ruby

Tags: ruby, active-directory

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to add a password to Active Directory accounts created with a Ruby script. An SSL connection is established with:

```
ldap = LDAP::SSLConn.new(LDAP_HOST, SSL_PORT)
```

Plain text passwords are run through a function to return a base 64 UTF-16LE string.

```
def convert_to_unicode pwd
    unicode_pwd = pwd.encode("UTF-16LE")
    return Base64.encode64(unicode_pwd)
end
```

Adding entries to AD aren't an issue but as soon as a password is put in it returns an error 53: unwilling to perform. The passwords that are being passed in meet the AD requirements and don't have any problems when done through a bash script. For example running the following through convert_to_unicode should return a quoted new_Password1 for AD to set.

```
'"new_Password1"'
```

Wondering if anyone has anything useful that they can point me towards that I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to just run encoding to UTF-16LE?

```
  def microsoft_encode_password pwd
    ret = ""
    pwd = "\"" + pwd + "\""
    pwd.length.times{|i| ret+= "#{pwd[i..i]}\000" }
    ret
  end
```

Comment: This was it thanks. Looks like I was trying to be too clever by half.